# expandable list view

Tags: android

main Activity:

```
public class ListActivityEx extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
LayoutInflater inflate;
ExpandableListAdapter adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    adapter = new MyCustomExpand(this);
    ExpandableListView expand = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListView_profile);
    expand.setAdapter(adapter);

}

}
```

Adapter class:

```
public class MyCustomExpand extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
LayoutInflater infalInflater;
private String[] groups = { "Test1", "Test2", "Test3" };

private String[][] children = {

{ "neelinfo", "MobileApp", "HYD" },

{ "rajesh", "palepu", "narasimha" },

{ "Android", "iphone", "J2ME" } };

// Add these lines to your code
private Context context;

public MyCustomExpand(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}


public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return children[groupPosition][childPosition];
}

public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return children[groupPosition].length;
}

public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_row, null);
    }

    TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.childname3);
    textView.setText(getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).toString());
    return convertView;
}
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return groups[groupPosition];
}

public int getGroupCount() {
    return groups.length;
}

public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        switch (groupPosition) {
        case 0:

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.group_row, null,
                    false);
            holder.textView = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.childname);
            Log.d("heading", getGroup(groupPosition).toString());
            holder.textView.setText(getGroup(groupPosition).toString());

            break;
        case 1:
            infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.group_row2, null,
                    false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.textView = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.childname11);
            // holder.textView.setText(getGroup(groupPosition).toString());
            Log.d("heading", getGroup(groupPosition).toString());

            holder.textView.setText(getGroup(groupPosition).toString());
        case 2:
            infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.group_row2, null,
                    false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.textView = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.childname11);
            // holder.textView.setText(getGroup(groupPosition).toString());
            Log.d("heading", getGroup(groupPosition).toString());
            holder.textView.setText(getGroup(groupPosition).toString());
        }
    }
    return convertView;
}

public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}

public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView textView;
}

}
```

Comment: i m getting verity output ifr i click the group position 1..i m getting chaild of 2nd group....i dont know why?? can any one please help me??? i need custon Android Expandablelist

Answer (score 0):

That's because you don't have `break` in `case 1:`. and 'case 2'